# forward snmp traps from host to docker container (telegraf)

Tags: docker, snmp, telegraf

Trying to get SNMP traps to forward to a docker container (telegraf)... from the main host interface.... I can see the incoming traps in tcpdump on the host....thoughts?

```html
telegraf:
    image: telegraf
    container_name: telegraf
    restart: always
    environment:
      HOST_PROC: /rootfs/proc
      HOST_SYS: /root/sys
      HOST_ETC: /root/etc
    volumes:
      - /opt/monitoring/telegraf:/rtc/telegraf/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /sys:/rootfs/sys
      - /proc:/rootfs/proc
      - /etc:/rootfs/etc
    links:
     - influxdb
    ports:
     - "8092:8092/udp"
     - 8094:8094
     - "8125:8125/udp"
     - "162:162/udp"
    networks:
      - monitoring
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is to bind your applications running in the container to 0.0.0.0: rather than  localhost :)

Works now